# BASH: Modify the content of array by its name stored in variable

Tags: arrays, bash

Suppose I have created an associative array `aaa` by `declare -A aaa` and `aaa[bbb]=0`, and I have `var=aaa`. How can I make `aaa[bbb]` increase by 1 using only `var` and `bbb` since I may not know the exact name of the array in the runtime.

I have tried `eval "(($var[bbb]++))"` but it didn't work.

Thanks!

Comment: Your code works for me.  What shell are you using?  How is it failing?  How are you checking the result of your code?

Comment: By the way, using `eval` may open up code injection risks if you cannot guarantee that the content of variables is safe (for instance, if the content of `var` is passed as a parameter or read from a file).

Comment: @Fred I tried `echo ${!var}` and just got a blank line. I'm using bash.

Comment: Try `echo "${aaa[bbb]}"`, you will see it worked.  You are using an incorrect method to display the content of the array.

Comment: You can do this to expand the whole array : `i="$var[@]" ; echo "${!i}"`.

Comment: @Fred I tried `eval echo \${$var[@]}` and found that it worked. Thank you!

Comment: @Fred and I finally found a missing ")" in my code that leads to all the errors...

Comment: There are correct ways to use `eval` (and `eval` is not the only way you can have code injection risks in your scripts), but it is tricky to use well, and in many cases, if you have a way to achieve your purpose without it, it is likely to be safer.

Comment: @Fred Thank you for that suggestion!

Comment: @Fred: `declare -p foo` is a simpler and more reliable way to see what's in `$foo` (works wirh a variable containing `foo` as well).

Comment: @rici Do you mean just for checking out for debugging/curiosity purposes, or for actual use in a script to replace an expansion?

Comment: @fred for debugging although it is also occasionally useful for serialisation such as saving and restoring.

Comment: I don't even see the need for `eval`; `(($var[bbb]++))` increments the value just fine. `$var` expands to `aaa`, and the arithmetic statement itself takes care of dereferencing `aaa[bbb]`.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is important enough to note in an answer, rather than just a comment. You *do not* need `eval` here. Arithmetic statements do their own dereferencing of variables independent of parameter expansion, so simply using parameter expansion to replace `var` with `aaa` is sufficient.

```
bash-4.4$ declare -A aaa
bash-4.4$ aaa[bbb]=0
bash-4.4$ ((aaa[bbb]++))
bash-4.4$ echo ${aaa[bbb]}
1
bash-4.4$ var=aaa
bash-4.4$ (($var[bbb]++))
bash-4.4$ echo ${aaa[bbb]}
2
```